# regex/preg_match alternating between numeric and alpha separated by space

Tags: php, regex

My string separates digits and alpha (phrases) by space.  The digits and alpha alternate.
So in the example below there are 6 ACT YE.  And the string continues with another set of digit then alpha.

Can't seem to get the right pattern to do the following...

Example String:
6 ACT YE 1000 FH 6 ACT YE 10000 ACT FC 32000 ACT

Should come out like:

```
[0] = 6
[1] = ACT YE
[2] = 1000
[3] = FH
[4] = 6
[5] = ACT YE
[6] = 10000
[7] = ACT FC
[8] = 32000
[9] = ACT
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = preg_split("/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\D)|(?<=\D)\s+(?=\d)/",$input);
```

This splits the subject string on spaces, but only if exactly one of "the stuff before" and "the stuff after" is a digit.

Comment: Thanks @Braj - it's worth noting that in your demo, the highlighted spaces are the ones that will be used to split the string :)

Comment: Nice splitting work, +1. Another solution would be to match on `\d+|[^ \d]+(?: [^ \d]+)*`, i.e. `$regex = '/\d+|[^ \d]+(?: [^ \d]+)*/';
$count = preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);`